# How to password protect opening specific app without disabling notifications

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-time

I'd like to password-protect an app, so that every time that I open the app, I'll need to enter a password (the idea is to make it more burdensome to access the app). Right now, I can password-protect the app by going to ScreenTime, activating the ScreenTime passcode, and putting a 1-minute app limit on the app. However, this also completely disables notifications. Is there a way to password-protect the app but still allow notifications? Ideally, this would be something that works on any iPhone 6 and up, although any solution is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: I can help. IS this for the iphone xs?

Comment: Ideally for any iPhone 6 or newer, but yes, even just a solution for an iPhone xs would be great. What did you have in mind? Thanks!